# Is it possible to fill reviewers from Contributors group on creating Pull Request on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

Is it possible to fill reviewers from Contributors group on creating Pull Request?

Is it possible out of the box or need to install some extension?

Comment: What do you mean "fill reviewers"? If you set the contributors group as a reviewer, members of that group will be reviewers. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you want it to pre-fill the reviewers with a set list, if so then you want to go into Project Settings - Repositories and set a policy on the relevant branch to automatically include reviewers:

[image]